# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException with latest versions of SDK build tools

Tags: android

I have a working Android project which started crashing with the runtime exception "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException" after upgrading to the latest version of the SDK build tools.  The crash happens when I call setContentView() from my main activity's onCreate().  The resource ID given in the exception matches the one of the main activity's layout.  I've been able to work around the problem by specifying an older version of the build tools (placing the line "sdk.buildtools=20.0" in the project.properties file, and installing the old one through the SDK Manager).  In experimenting I found the latest version of the build tools (21.0.1 as of this writing) as well as version 21 cause the crash.  But using version 20 (or older) works around the problem.

I have a hard time thinking the latest versions of the build tools are completely broken, so I assume there's something peculiar about my project causing this.  Anyone else seeing it?

I should mention also that I did try the general suggestions for this error in many other SO posts -- clean the project, delete the R.java and regenerate it, restart Eclipse, etc.

Edit: This did indeed turn out to be a bug in the build tools. Thanks Adam for pointing out the aapt.exe patch.  Also, after doing some more digging today, I discovered by extracting the APK contents that the "bad" version was completely missing the resources.arsc file -- so maybe this will offer some clues to anyone else that comes across this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629) in the building tools. They will probably fix it in the next version.

here is workaround https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629#c76 taht works for me. Use it with version 21.0.1.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing me to that thread!  Installing the patched aapt.exe did indeed fix my problem (which it sounds like will be fixed in build tools 21.0.2).  Oddly though, I don't get any of the aapt errors or crashes reported on the Google bug report.  I looked through the verbose output and even ran aapt manually from the command line to confirm - it doesn't report anything wrong. Anyway, thanks!